# Can I use 'sed' to search and replace K number of LINE occurrences?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to do a search and replace on many files. I'm first thinking of using 'sed' but I think my requirements may make 'sed' inappropriate.

In brief, let's say I've got a file with 4 occurrences of 'KEYWORD'. They occur once in a line, but on 4 different lines.

Question: Can I use 'sed' to replace the first two occurrences only. If not, would you please recommend other tools available in Linux. For the time being, let's not discuss how to do this with programming languages (python, ruby, java).

I've come across how to change K number of occurrences within a single line, but I haven't seen how to replace K number of line occurrences (if you know what I mean).

If you have any ideas, please let me know.

Comment: One option is of course to append lines to pattern space until it has `k` occurrences of the keyword, then do `s` and quit. This doesn't scale well with `k` and is not very neat though.

Comment: I think (but I'm not 100% sure) you're right that this isn't a good fit for sed. Unless the file is sorted, this basically requires you to "backtrack" an arbitrary number of lines if a third occurrence is found, which sed isn't really made for.

Comment: Will it always be two occurrences, or would you want a general solution for `K` occurrences?

Comment: I have already implemented some surrounding bash script to give me what K should be in a given file. So to answer your question, I do need a general solution, but I may already have it. I just need to handle this compartmentalized case of replacing K lines. FYI, I'm investigating 'awk' right now. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

awk might be handy here:

```
awk 'i<2{i+=sub(/KEYWORD/, "FOOBAR")} 1' file
```

Comment: I'm going to have to learn a bit about 'awk' before I can try this out. Which I will do right now. Be back soon. Thanks.

Comment: Not only does that work, but I think it's the best-fitting solution for this problem. Many thanks, anubhava!

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/KEYWORD/{G;h;/(\n[^\n]*){3}/!s/KEYWORD/REPLACEMENT/;s/\n.*//}' file
```

Use the `-r` switch to make regexp easier on the eye.

Focus on lines containing the `KEYWORD` only.

Use the hold space (HS) as a variable counting the number of times the `KEYWORD` is encounterd. Append the hold space to the pattern space (PS) and thus introduce a newline (`\n`) for each line appended. The newline character is unique in that in normal processing it is removed from the pattern space by sed. Having appended the HS replace the HS by the current PS (ready for the next substitution). If there are less than 3 lines in the PS then replace the `KEYWORD` with the `REPLACEMENT`. Remove the appended lines and continue processing as normal.

N.B. The number `3` (n+1) can be changed to whatever number is desired, also by removing the negation of the substitution (`!`) the reverse i.e. the number of `KEYWORDS` encountered before substitution, is effected.

On reflection a more versatile solution:

```
sed -r '/KEYWORD/{G;h;/^[^\n]*(\n[^\n]*){1,2}$/s/KEYWORD/REPLACEMENT/;s/\n.*//}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Because this is also tagged with "sed" and for fun (and probably to demonstrate how sed is *not* the best tool here): you could use

```
repl=2
for (( i = 0; i < repl; ++i )); do
    sed -i '0,/KEYWORD/ s//substitution/' infile
done
```

That is, replace the first occurrence however many times you want. Disadvantage: this processes the whole file for each loop, and the `0` address (in case `KEYWORD` appears on the first line) is a GNU sed extension.

I'm pretty sure it could be done completely in sed (actually, [I am sure](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/proof-that-sed-is-turing-complete/)), but counting is not pretty, see for example the "[Incrementing a number](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Increment-a-number)" bit in the sed manual.